# Getting error as "404 not found" when refresh page in react js

Tags: reactjs

I am Getting error as "404 not found" when refresh page in  react js. it's working on localhost but when i moved code on server then  Getting this error.

Comment: Please read [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: Read error_log file it will tell you what to do.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this as well and has to do with server configuration. What you need to do is configure your server that when visiting **/***, return your index.html.

Now you probably only have **/** configured to return index.html.

How to do that, depends on your technology:

**Express**

```js
app.get('/*', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'path/to/your/index.html'), function(err) {
    if (err) {
      res.status(500).send(err)
    }
  })
})
```

**Apache Htaccess**

```js
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to configure your server in a way that if no resource is found for a request then the server should always return an index.html file.

You can use the below code:

```
if(process.env.NODE_ENV==='production'){
    app.use(express.static('client/build'));
    const path=require('path');
    app.get('*',(req,res)=>{
    res.sendfile(path.resolve(__dirname,'client','build','index.html'));
  })
}
```